# How do I display line numbers in emacs (not in the mode line)?

Tags: line-numbers, linum-mode

I know how to display line numbers (and columns) in the mode-line, but I'd like emacs to display the line numbers for all the lines on the left-hand side. I've seen this done in vim and other text editors. How do I do this for emacs?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

For Emacs version >= 26 you should use `display-line-numbers-mode` or `global-display-line-numbers-mode`.

You can run the command with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`display-line-numbers-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd>`global-display-line-numbers-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> to try it.

Another good idea is to use `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)` in your init.el to automatically enable that mode in all programming modes.

See [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers)

Comment: You might also find `(global-display-line-numbers-mode)` useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what init.el is, but I assume you can add that to your `~/.emacs` file

Answer (score 22):

`M-x linum-mode` will do the trick.  If you wish to effect this for all buffers, then `M-x global-linum-mode` will do this.

Comment: Do you know a way I can make this permanent?

Comment: (per the suggestion of nispio and mgoszcz2) addition of `(global-linum-mode)` to your .emacs.d/init.el file will make it permanent.  I find global-linum-mode to be a bit excessive, and mgoszcz2's suggestion for enabling it only in certain modes is a good one.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Emacs 26 or newer, you can use `display-line-numbers-mode`.

from `etc/NEWS.26`:

> ** Emacs now supports optional display of line numbers in the buffer. This is similar to what 'linum-mode' provides, but much faster and
>   doesn't usurp the display margin for the line numbers.  Customize the
>   buffer-local variable 'display-line-numbers' to activate this optional
>   display.  Alternatively, you can use the 'display-line-numbers-mode'
>   minor mode or the global 'global-display-line-numbers-mode'.  When
>   using these modes, customize 'display-line-numbers-type' with the same
>   value as you would use with 'display-line-numbers'.

Comment: I like it so much, but my muscle memory still goes `M-x linum-mode` - so I did `(advice-add 'linum-mode :override 'display-line-numbers-mode)`.

Answer (score 8):

`nlinum-mode` is another option. It has the same interface as `linum-mode`, so you can use the same hooks, but it uses a different technology to be more performant. Quote from `nlinum.el`:

> ;; This is like linum-mode, but uses jit-lock to be (hopefully) more efficient.

You can install it via GNU Elpa via the usual `list-packages`.

http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html

Answer (score 4):

Certainly `linum-mode` is a good choice.
If you don't always want to see line numbers, like me, you can use this trick from the excellent [What the .emacs.d!?](http://whattheemacsd.com/key-bindings.el-01.html) blog.

This temporarily enables `linum-mode` when you run `goto-line`.

Here's the code from his blog:

```
(global-set-key [remap goto-line] 'goto-line-with-feedback)

(defun goto-line-with-feedback ()   "Show line numbers temporarily, while prompting for the line number input"   (interactive)   (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (linum-mode 1)
        (goto-line (read-number "Goto line: ")))
    (linum-mode -1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what my teacher tells us to set line-display-mode always on. Add this in your `.emacs` file.

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
(setq linum-format "%3d ")
```

OTTO: Professor William Knottenbelt

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>M-x</kbd> and type just `linum` (or even `linu` will work), then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to automatically execute `linum-mode`. No need to type the longer `linum-mode`.

Also, usually you just want to go to one chosen line of interest because of an error message. Then press <kbd>M-x</kbd>, type `goto-line`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type the line of choice.

Answer (score 1):

A better way may be is to use `prog-mode` as a whole instead of doing for all programming language.

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

Though it doesn't work for mode other than programming langauges. But it is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

To have it always enabled by default in Emacs 26+

**~/.emacs**

```
;; Display line numbers
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

Comment: Welcome!  I think this point is already covered by the previous answers.

Comment: @Dan They mention what can be used but it is not as clear as my answer.