# Setting relative line numbers when in programming modes

Tags: line-numbers

Looking to set relative line numbers when in programming modes.
Looking through the older posts I see a way to set line numbers based on the mode - [How do I display line numbers in emacs (not in the mode line)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/280/23885) :

> [@AnthonyB](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/22122/anthonyb) : `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)`

Currently, use `(setq-default display-line-numbers 'relative)` in my init file for relative line numbers, however, would like to use this setting on a per mode basis partially all programming modes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display-line-numbers` is a buffer-local variable.  To enable line numbers for only certain modes, do not use `setq-default`.  Instead, use `setq` ... something like this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (setq display-line-numbers 'relative)))
```

Or, use a preferred major-mode hook such as the `perl-mode-hook` or `html-mode-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'name-of-major-mode-hook (lambda () (setq display-line-numbers 'relative)))
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for.